# Getting a jqGrid with postData filter on initial load to only display client-side filtered rows

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, client-side

We have a jqGrid that initially fetches its rows via the built-in ajax fetch returning a `json` object.  We then do filtering / searching on the client side using custom functions to build the postData filters and then later use them to set the filterToolbar widgets to match.

Our issue is that for certain use cases the initial page load will have postData filters set but the grid does not act on them.  For example, we might have a filter for "column A='foo' AND column B='bar'" and on initial page load the filterToolbar widgets reflect this but the grid displays all rows.  To get the grid to act on the postData filters we have to cause the grid to reload.  This produces the visual UI artifact that our users see the full grid and half a second later the grid updates to display only the filtered rows.

Essentially, what we are doing is

```
loadcomplete: function (data) {
  if (ifirstTime) {
    // at this point jqGrid("getGridParam", "postData") contains filters set from cookies
    $grid.jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "local" });
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.trigger("reloadGrid");
    }, 100);
    firstTime = false;
}
// the grid shows all rows now.  after the timeout above fires the 
// grid will be updated to show the filtered rows only.
```

We have tried manually setting the jqGrid data in the `beforeProcessing` event and some other tricks to try and avoid reloading the grid.  It looks like being able to call the `populate()` method buried within jqGrid might help, but getting a context to be able to call it has been challenging.

Most other answers I've come across deal with server side filtering and the few that client side answers seem to settle for this grid reloading method.

Is there any method to let jqGrid load its data via its normal method when datatype is `json` and then apply client side `postData` filters prior to the initial grid rendering.  We want the filtered grid to be the first thing the user sees rather than seeing the unfiltered grid initially.

Any alternative methods to hide the first grid view (with all rows) for the case when `postData` filters exist would also be helpful as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You described the problem very good. The problem could be solved only by more deep changes in jqGrid.

I develop [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork starting with the licence agreement of the main jqGrid repository are changed in version 4.7.1 and jqGrid are renamed in Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) the prices of Guriddo jqGrid JS [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). Starting with the start of free jqGrid project at the end 2014 I rewrote many old parts of jqGrid. After re-writing some features was implemented relatively easy.

If you would replace your current jqGrid to free jqGrid then you can use just new option `forceClientSorting: true` which works in combination with `loadonce: true`. The option force applying of client side sorting and filtering the data **before** the first page will be displayed by jqGrid. In the way you can load any JSON data, from some public source for example where you can't change anything on the server side, and then apply required filtering and sorting on the client side. You should remove the old tricks from `loadComplete` and all should work directly.

By the way, the easiest way to use free jqGrid is loading it from CDN. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That option in your free jqGrid fork is exactly what we needed.  However, using your free jqGrid has introduced lots of "lag" in horizontal scrolling of the grid in IE 11 from style calculations being applied to every cell in the grid (doesn't happen in Chrome).  Is this something you've seen before in transitioning from the old jqGrid to your jqGrid?

Comment: @casey: You are welcome! Sorry, but I don't understand what "lag" you mean. I changed in free jqGrid default values of some parameters so that there are exist less misunderstandings especially for the new users. It allows to use jqGrid with very few options (see the demos [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html)). For example default value of `height` is `"auto"` now and the default value of `datatype` will be `"local"` *if `data` parameter is specified. If no `data` parameter is specified then the default value of `datatype` will be the old `"xml"` unless `jsonReader`.

Comment: In short the lag is between that the scrolling between the grid body and header is not visually happening at the same time.  From the start of scrolling there is a large (around a second) before the `scrollGrid` method in free jqGrid is called and the header (and footer) scoll positions are updated.  This seems to be style interactions with IE 11 as its profiler is reporting that it is calculating styles for every grid cell (2000 or so) in the grid when scrolling is happening.

Comment: @casey: Sorry, but I still can't follow you, probably I have no idea in which way you use jqGrid and with which options. Some code or at least some picture could be helpful to understand what you mean. Could it be that you use virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1` or `scroll: true`)? jqGrid can be very difficult from TreeGrid, data grouping, pivot tables, subgrids and so on. One can use `datatype: "local"`, "xml", "json", "jsonp", one can use `loadonce: true` and so on. It's really difficult to understand you if I have no idea what from above (and many other features) you use.

Comment: I'm not in front of the code now but I don't think we are using virtual scrolling and nothing fancy like tree or subgrids. It's also isolated to IE 11 and at this point thinking it's a performance bug on their end, not your code. Thanks for the information above.

Comment: @casey: You are welcome! Just contact me it you find any problem, but please try to prepare the demo, some code fragments or at least some pictures, which reproduces the problem. If I would be able to reproduce or at least understand exactly the problem I could try to help you. By the way you can use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) utility to create (record) animated gifs instead of static screen-shorts. It could shows some strange animation effects which you could have.